# Mongodb 3.0.15 on Ubuntu 14.04 - data disappeared - possible causes?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-14.04

I have been logging bitcoin order books and trades for the past 20 days in mongodb. 1 database [bitmicro], 1 collection for trades, 1 collection for books.

now suddently all the data is gone and the logger has started from scratch since yesterday.

The mongo log doesnt show any entries since October. And a new database appeared called Warning exactly when the data loss happened

```
> show dbs
Warning   0.078GB
bitmicro  0.453GB
local     0.078GB
```

After some reading it might be the case, that the filesize of the collection became too big and ubuntu deleted it?

Since the log /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log  doesnt show any entries since starting the server, how can I find out what happened?

Comment: make sure your mongodb secure (authentication is enabled) and it's better limit the access to local or limited ips.

Comment: @achuth db access is limited to 127.0.0.1

Comment: @user670186 the existence of the `Warning` database implies that your database was accessed by a malicious 3rd party, and your database is exposed to the internet without any authentication. Please see https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/how-to-avoid-a-malicious-attack-that-ransoms-your-data and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/

Comment: yes, indeed thasnk for clarification

Answer (score 1):

the existence of the Warning database implies that your database was accessed by a malicious 3rd party, and your database is exposed to the internet without any authentication.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/